# SSRS - filtering out records

Tags: ssrs-tablix

From the Tablix Properties > Change Filters screen, I can add and delete filters.

The Field that I'm working with is called MBA_Account.

If I set it to Expression: MBA_Account; Operator =; value: Administrative; it works.  I get just 1 line in the output called Administrative, and the aggregated data that correlates with that account.

There are 30 records in the database, I'm only interested in including 10 in my report.

To bring in the other 9 accounts to the report, should I add more filters or should I use an AND operator set in just 1 filter in order to effectively isolate just the Account codes I want included in the output?

In other words:

Option A)
Expression: MBA_Account
Operator: =
Value: and(Administrative, Salaries, Repairs)

Option B)
Expression: MBA_Account
Operator: =
Value: Administrative
; and then repeat the filter but change the value per line (this option doesn't seem to be working)

Comment: If you're only interested in 10 records then why don't you change your dataset query to include only those 10?

Comment: I see what you're saying... right click the dataset > query > and then adjust the the select statement to include an isolating where clause, i.e. Where MBA_Account = x,y,z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your dataset query to include a WHERE clause like this:

> Where MBA_Account IN ('Administrative','Salaries','Repairs')

By doing this you only return the records you're interested in seeing and your report does not have to do any filtering (at the Tablix level).

Comment: That will definitely solve my problem.  I'll mark answered when I'm able in 3 minutes.  Thanks!